# Self join table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I want to create a view by doing some select on two huge tables I have (one with over 10 million lines)

the first one has the following columns, we'll call it WRSD :

> ID_Deal,Year, GVKEY_ACQ, TARGET_GVKEY

in this table we have some transaction with an ID for the acquiror and another one for the target (hence de GVKEY)

The second one is called mytable :

> ID_firm, year, subcat, totalpat, numpat

`WRSD.GVKEY_acq` and `WRSD.TARGET_GVKEY` reference `mytable.ID_firm`

And I want to select a table that will show :

> ID_DEAL, GVKEY_acq, year, subcat, totalpat, numpat, TARGET_GVKEY,
>   totalpat, numpat

So that I can compare the data between the two firms for every subcategory.

I tried a lot of queries but none of them worked, does someone have any clue about how to solve this problem ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any chance `WRSD.GVKEY_acq` and  `WRSD.TARGET_GVKEY` reference `mytable.ID_firm` ?

Comment: Yes they do, sorry if it was unclear !

Comment: Join the same table twice. Give it a separate alias each time

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MySQL, but if @Serg's commment is correct, you should be able to do something similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    W.Year,
    A.ID_firm AS 'Aquiring Firm', 
    B.ID_firm AS 'Target Firm'
  FROM WRSD AS W
  INNER JOIN myTable AS A ON W.GVKEY_ACQ = A.ID_firm
  INNER JOIN myTable AS B ON W.TARGET_GVKEY = B.ID_firm
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems good for me but i couldn't execute it, too much data. I'll try it on a faster PC and see how it goes !

Comment: Try "SELECT TOP(5) ..."

Answer (score 0):

What if you have two firms (mytable.ID_firm) with different subcat in the same WRSD? Should that be skipped? If so, also make A.subcat = B.subcat. But it seems that either you have a design problem, or you are trying to do something that the data available isn't happy about.